# Which tools can wrapper up a linux binary with all its dependencies to be used on a different system?

Tags: linux

I know this tool exists, but I can't remember the search terms for google.

I'm looking for a tool which takes a binary on linux with dynamic library dependencies and wrappers that binary with some chroot'ing into a local copy of the environment such that I can copy that directory onto a new machine and all the dynamic libraries are in that directory and the binary can find them.

What tool am I looking for?

Comment: Requests for software recommendations or even a particular tool can be regarded as off-topic here so your question could be closed. Try changing it to "how do I" format, the answer could well include the tool you are looking for, or a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for are **Statifier** (http://statifier.sourceforge.net) and **Ermine** (http://www.magicermine.com).

Statifier is free software whereas Ermine is proprietary.

If you only want to use it on the same distribution you created the file, you might also take a look at AppImageKit (http://www.portablelinuxapps.org)

Comment: Bingo!  I just couldn't remember which terms to search for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tool to show you "all" of the dependencies is called 'ldd'. I don't know of anything that combines ldd and a packager.

Why the quotes around all? Because ldd shows you the dependencies on startup. It shows the ones that were satisfied by checking the binary to see which are hard coded into the binary as needed libs. But the binary can always ask for other libs while it's running.

Besides that, the binary may be calling for config files that are compiled into specific known locations.  Ldd can't do anything for you here.

You probably need something more like strace and see every file your app touches, not just the dynamic line.

Comment: I'm aware of `ldd` as well as what `dlopen` does, but this is a class of tool that cuts the gordian knot of dependency hell by simply including all the included shared objectsin a container and then `chroot`'ing so that the binary finds all the libraries underneath that directory.  There are two implementations of this tool but the name escapes my memory.  It is like creating a psuedo-static binary after the binary has already been created. It can make a binary portable between distros where LD_LIBRARY_PATH is different.

Comment: @RossRogers "across distros" do you mean `alien`?

Comment: [alien](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/alien-use-any-package-any-distribution) is interesting.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.  I was actually looking for [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/) and [Ermine](http://www.magicermine.com/) per FSMaxbB.